# How to collect same word from string using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript string with some repeated word. I want collect them with comma separated.
The string is -

```
1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1233_3-33-23-master=1236
```

The output should be -

```
1232,1233,1236
```

Comment: can you explain bit more?

Comment: Is it a JavaScript or PHP problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. This code is my assumption, I don't know this is an efficient way.

```
var str = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1233_3-33-23-master=1236";
var result = "";
var strSplit = str.split("_");
for (var dk=0;dk< strSplit.length;dk++){
if ( (dk + 1) === strSplit.length){
   result += strSplit[dk].split("-master=")[1];
}else{
    result += strSplit[dk].split("-master=")[1] + ",";
}
}
console.log(result);
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNy56/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following solutions :

```
var input = '1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1233_3-33-23-master=1236';
var output = input.replace(/.*?=(\d+)/g, ',$1').slice(1);
var output = (input.match(/\d+(?=_|$)/g) || []).join();
var output = (input.match(/master=\d+/g) || []).join().replace(/master=/g, '');
```

MDN doc : [String match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [String replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [String slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [Array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1233_3-33-23-master=1236";

str = str.replace(/-master=/g,';');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your String value is fix than you can use this function in javascript that is give you proper value

```
function test()
{
    var str = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1233_3-33-23-master=1236";
    var finalvalue="";
    var value="";
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(str.charAt(i)=='='){
            value="";
            for(var j=i+1;j<i+5;j++){
                value = value + str.charAt(j);
             }
            if(finalvalue=="")
                    finalvalue = value;
                else
                    finalvalue = finalvalue +","+ value;

         }
    }
    alert(finalvalue);

}
```